# Python type hinting compatibility

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, type-hinting

I am writing a code that handles Python AST nodes, that should be compatible for both Python 2 and Python 3.

However, Python 3 has `ast.Try`, where Python 2 has `ast.TryFinally` and `ast.TryExcept`, so I need to use `visit_` aliases to handle both cases.

If I write my node visitor code using compatibility aliases, like the following, my pre-commit mypy check will complain when using Python 2, that `error: Name 'ast.Try' is not defined`:

```
import ast

class Visitor(ast.NodeVisitor):


    def visit_Try(self, node):  # type: (ast.Try) -> None
        ...
    visit_TryFinally = visit_Try  # python 2 compatible
```

If I instead use `ast.TryFinally` in the type hint, it will instead complain `error: Name 'ast.TryFinally' is not defined` if I run it in Python 3. I know that I can use a more general type for the node, but that makes me writing a lot of `# type: ignore` in the code which I don't want.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: which `mypy` are you using? I have no errors for given snippet on `mypy 0.641`, also can you post error message(s) as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mypy knows [how to handle Python version checks](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#python-version-and-system-platform-checks), and you could use conditional *type aliases* to pick the right type for the right Python version:

```
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    TryNode = ast.Try
else:
    TryNode = ast.TryFinally

class Visitor(ast.NodeVisitor):


    def visit_Try(self, node):  # type: (TryNode) -> None
        # ...
    visit_TryFinally = visit_Try  # python 2 compatible
```

You can further save yourself the runtime cost of the `if sys.version_info` tests by placing that code in a [`if TYPE_CHECKING:` test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING).

As a side note: if you are handling `ast.Try` in Python 3 to track both `finally:` and `except ...:` components of the `try` statement, you want to handle both `ast.TryFinally` and `ast.TryExcept` in Python 2, as before Python 2.5, you could only use `try...finally` *or* `try...except` in one statement.